# Looping through subdirectories and storing the paths in an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Function GetSubDir(ByVal sDir)

Dim oFS As New FileSystemObject
Dim oDir

Set oDir = oFS.GetFolder(sDir)
For Each oSub In oDir.SubFolders
    MsgBox oSub.Path
    GetSubDir oSub.Path
Next oSub
End Function
```

I would like to modify it so that each subdirectory path is stored into an array, however I have no idea how to implement this, or if it is even possible. Can anybody help?

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: I know how to create an array, but I do not know how to make it so that each time it loops to a subdirectory it inserts the values into the array. I have a dynamic array but no idea how to input with this code, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in your code create a basic array, and make it larger for every sub-directory as below...

```
dim myArray()
dim iCount as integer

iCount=1

Set oDir = oFS.GetFolder(sDir)

' in your loop through the sub-directories...
For Each oSub In oDir.SubFolders
    Redim Preserve myArray(iCount)
    myArray(iCount) = oSub.path
    iCount=iCount+1
Next
```

hth

Philip

PS. I also recommend the articles suggested by the others...

it's always going to be better if you can catch the fish yourself rather than having one thrown at you :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I have been reading those articles for days, sometimes all it takes is for an answer for it to all slot together.